# How to prevent an unregistered user from commenting in a forum or a chat?

Tags: php, permissions, chat, forums

I would like to create a discussion forum and a live chat in which only registered users can reply. How would I go about this using PHP? Do I need permissions?

Comment: "*..Do I need permissions?*" What permission?

Comment: you can set logged in user id in session and allow user to comment if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'])) only then user can comment

Comment: check session functionality to maintain user information .please refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php